# Find the largest string satisfying following constraints

Tags: permutations, dynamic-programming

Let the three integers $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$ representing the maximum count of alphabets $a$, $b$, $c$ in a string. Find the maximum length string such no three consecutive alphabets are same in the resultant string

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you face your difficulties?  What did you find with small test values for $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$?

Comment: i tried an iterative greedy approach where I start with the charachters having max frequencies and arrange them one after the other. After one of them is exhasusted, I do same with the left out charachter. But this approach doesn't seem to give correct answer always